How to deal with SQS messages older than the max visibility timeout (12 hours)?
I have a dead-letter queue where a bunch of the messages that got sent there are now older than the maximum visibility timeout (12 hours). I can't seem to delete them from the console or using boto3. Is there any way to delete these messages individually or do I have to purge the whole queue?
Thanks!

The normal way to delete messages is to receive them via ReceiveMessage() and then use the ReceiptHandle in a call to DeleteMessage(). You should be able to do it via the console too -- what happens when you view a message and try to delete it in the console?

I get an error that the receipt handle has expired. And since the messages are older than the maximum visibility time, using the change visibility API doesn't seem to fix the problem either.

When you call ReceiveMessage()` on the DLQ, it will give you the message and a 'fresh' ReceiptHandle that you can use to delete the message.
